# How to find the exact value of $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }\:\frac{2^{n+1}}{\left(n+1\right)3^n}$

Tags: calculus

I know that the series given converges by using the series ratio test, but how would I find the exact value?

$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }\:\frac{2^{n+1}}{\left(n+1\right)3^n}$

The hint given was: use geometric series to write $-ln(1-x)$ as a power series.
Any help to get started would be great.

Comment: Have you written down the power series?  What is the difficulty?

Comment: What have you done with the hint?  Can you show us your results from following the hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting started: Recall that 
$$
\int_0^x\frac{1}{1-t}\mathrm dt=-\ln(1-x)
$$
for $|x|<1$. Recall also that 
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n
$$
for $|x|<1$. So, putting it together
$$
-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^xt^n\mathrm dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}
$$
and....